# Scripting an msdos program using a .bat file

Tags: automation, batch-file

i have a msdos program that when you execute it he ask you for 3 texts, you need to answer the firts, hit enter, then the second, hit enter and soo...

The think is that the answers are always the same, how using a .bat file can i script that? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean they are the same as if everytime you run those three, at anytime, the answer is still the same? Or just once in a while?

Comment: maybe this image will help you: http://img261.imageshack.us/img261/3069/sinttulo3es.jpg

Comment: DOS (finally) died with Windows ME, the appropriate term is "console application".

Answer (score 2):

If the answers are always the same, you can (often) redirect the standard input to a text file containing the answers (one on each line, and there should be a newline after the last answer)

```
Program.exe -option1 -option2 < answers.txt
```

I say "often" because some programs will code around the standard input, like "runas".

answers.txt just looks like this:

```
answer1
answer2
answer3
```

Comment: Thanks, but i dint explain well my self. There is no 3 program, is only one program who ask me tree questions, and then give a result. The answers are always 3, Answer1 (hit enter), Answer2 (hit enter), Answer3 (hit enter).

Comment: nop, maybe this image will help you: http://img261.imageshack.us/img261/3069/sinttulo3es.jpg

Comment: This will work for what you are asking. In answers.txt, insert your solutions (one on each line) into the file and it will run. If you want the rest returned, try something like this:

 Program.exe < answers.txt > result.txt

That will return your result in a text file.

Comment: dont work, i think is because the parameters, see this is what i made:http://img255.imageshack.us/img255/3032/sinttulo3ac.jpg

Comment: Make sure < answers.txt comes after all of your command line options.

Comment: dont work, i think is because the parameters, see this is what i made:img255.imageshack.us/img255/3032/sinttulo3ac.jpg

Comment: You need the newline character at the end of your last answer.  If you don't press enter at the end of the answer in the text file, it doesn't get sent to the program.

Answer (score 0):

In order to write a batch script to automate this task you would have to use a program that simulates key strokes in dos such as key-fake.

An alternative would be to use Windows Script Host which has this ability natively.

An example script (in javascript) would be something like:

```
var objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
var answer1 = a, answer2 = b, answer3 = c;


while(true) {
    var myProg = Wscript.Exec("MyProgram");

    WScript.Sleep = 100;

    WScript.Echo(answer1);
    WScript.SendKeys("{Enter}"); //Simulate Enter key
    WScript.Echo(answer2);
    WScript.SendKeys("{Enter}");
    WScript.Echo(answer3);
    WScript.SendKeys("{Enter}");
}
```

Save the script as myscript.js.

At a dos prompt run the following command:

cscript myscript.js

Press control-c to kill the script when you want it to stop.

To help you customize this script to your needs you can get more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98591fh7%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but i dint explain well my self. There is no 3 program, is only one program who ask me tree questions, and then give a result. The answers are always 3, Answer1 (hit enter), Answer2 (hit enter), Answer3 (hit enter).

Comment: maybe this image will help you: http://img261.imageshack.us/img261/3069/sinttulo3es.jpg

Comment: This script should still work for you, simply remove the while loop but keep the contents.